# gcloud alpha storage ls isn't finding uploaded file

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

I uploaded a folder structure with a single file inside to an existing gcloud storage bucket.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>gcloud alpha storage cp -r testfolder gs://auction-engine-upload
Copying file://testfolder\testSubfolder\MAXPOWER.png to gs://auction-engine-upload/testfolder/testSubfolder/MAXPOWER.png
  Completed files 1/1 | 10.0kiB/10.0kiB
```

Then I tried to verify the file was uploaded by using the ls command:

```
gcloud alpha storage ls gs://auction-engine-upload
```

This lists about 40 directories that are not the /testfolder directory, so I tried a few different ways to get only the /testfolder to list:

```
gcloud alpha storage ls gs://auction-engine-upload/testfolder
gcloud alpha storage ls gs://auction-engine-upload/testfolder/
gcloud alpha storage ls gs://auction-engine-upload/testfolder/*
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.storage.ls) One or more URLs matched no objects.
```

Am I screwing up syntax or is the file actually not uploaded?

Comment: Tried to replicate your issue and the command **gcloud alpha storage**
works on my end which displays the `testfolder` under the storage bucket name `auction-engine-upload`.

I also managed your error and found out that if you input a mispelled folder name this error occurs: **ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.storage.ls) One or more URLs matched no objects.**

Can you check if the `testfolder` existed in the bucket `auction-engine-upload` after you upload it. If not please upload a folder again, and then carefully review the folder name.

Comment: Sarah- Thanks for your attention.

Would you share the CLI command that you used to display the testfolder?

Comment: This is the CLI command I used **gcloud alpha storage ls gs://auction-engine-upload**. You can also try this **gsutil ls gs://auction-engine-upload**. Let me know if these commands work on your end.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out.  The folder doesn't exist in the gs://auction-engine-upload bucket and for some reason I can't create a new folder there by uploading a file (prob permissions).  I was able to upload it to a different folder, then use ls to find it.

Comment: It seems that you solved your issue, please post your answer to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to change the permissions in the bucket, so I had to have the account owner create another bucket and give me permission to create the file there.